# Angular Filter by value contained in array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Say I have a model like:

```
$scope.types = [
        {
            name: 'X1500',
            value: 'X1500',
            tags: ['GRE','GRB']
        },
        {
            name: 'VSH',
            value: 'VSH',
            tags: ['GRE','GRB']
        }
]
```

And I want to filter all types that has GRE in their tags. Something like:

```
"type.value as type.name for type in types | filter:types.tags='GRE'"
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the filter mentioned in the question does work :)